# Crash assigning Float[] to CMutablePointer<Float> in Swift

Tags: swift

If I assign a float array to a `CMutablePointer<Float>` in a Swift playground as follows, I get a runtime crash:

```
var floatArray:Float[] = Array(count: 3, repeatedValue: 2.5)
var floatPointer:CMutablePointer<Float> = &floatArray
```

Is my code incorrect (if so how?), or should I file this as a bug with Apple?

Comment: It compiles and runs using swift from the command-line, but not in the Xcode6-beta Playground.  So go ahead, and file a Playground bug report (might be a dup though).

Comment: @hotpaw2 Thanks. Just filed a bug report.

Answer (score 1):

Your param is a tab so you have to do like this

> var floatArray:Float[] = Array(count: 3, repeatedValue: 2.5)
>
> `var floatPointer:CMutablePointer<Float[]> = &floatArray`

Comment: using `CMutablePointer<Float[]>` causes exactly the same crash. I think this is an Xcode6-beta playground bug as suggested by @hotpaw2

Answer (score 0):

Your code, when compiled and run outside of the Playground:

```
var floatArray:Float[] = Array(count: 3, repeatedValue: 2.5)
var floatPointer:CMutablePointer<Float> = &floatArray

floatPointer.withUnsafePointer { (myPtr1 : UnsafePointer<Float>) -> () in
  var x = myPtr1.memory
  println("float array element 0 is \(x)")
}
```

prints 2.5

Comment: Sadly, the pointer functions are not well defined (documented). I would rather use `Array.withUnsafePointerToElements`. It seems more appropriate.

Comment: @Sulthan what do you mean re: using `withUnsafePointerToElements`, what if I e.g. need to pass an `CMutablePointer<T>` to one of one of the Cocoa APIs?